# How to keep lots of users' online information in a application scope container until theirs logout?

Tags: iphone, cakephp, status, simultaneous

`Hello,`
everybody.

We are developing an iPhone app which supported by a server-side that would be thousands of users online simultaneously such as Facebook or GTalk else.

What we want to implement is sending users present location periodically(e.g., 10mins) generated by GPS to the server-side for processing. And compare users' locations to find out who are around you. (Maybe this is something called as LBS)

So we think that users would not be inactivated(such as session timeout) until they logouted by themselves manually as theirs location information would be compared time and time again.

Then, how could we store location information for each user?
I saw some articles that suggest manage them in database, but some said session or cookie else.
But with so many users, database is said to be very bad performance, others said session is  too many and should be set to timeout in a shot while and cookie is a bad practice...

So guys, what is the common way to deal with this issue?

*By the way, we are using CakePHP1.3 and Xampp env for the server-side.

Best regards,
tech_me

Comment: I think you are late with that kind of service: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhyO1ObAIhQ

Comment: Thanks for providing us with this information. In fact, we knew that there are several apps that are similar to what we want to develop-and this category is called **LBS**, isn't it? But we have our _original ideas_ which these apps haven't had yet.;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the strengths of databases is searching through stored information, you'll most certainly want to use some kind of database since in this case you'll want to search for nearby users.

Sessions are usually used for information that is only relevant to one single user, not such a good fit for this case (although you could store session data in a database and possibly be able to search through them, it's probably not a very good design)

Cookies are really a way for the server to store information in the browser that is passed back to the server with every HTTP request, this won't really help you in this case either.

How about having the application send its location every few minutes, storing it in a database with a timestamp, and if the timestamp is older than say 30 minutes, just consider the user offline?

Comment: Sorry for my poor knowledge about session.  
>Sessions are usually used for information that is only relevant to one single user.  
You mean whatever I put one user(from one client) in the session, when the other users come, they could not be saved in the session which I was thinking is global variable at the same time(or say period)? So we could not compare theirs locations? Oh, my God...

We only want to have one global(such as session) container for thousands of locations handling, and changing individual location for each user in the container when the next location uploaded from them.

Comment: Sessions are _per user_ storage, which means that when you store something there, it's only accessible by that same user. In other words, if you store the location there, the only one that can read the location is the same user, users cannot see each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your correction!  
About the database way, do we have to get the locations time and time again from it and put them into an global array(or say container) in the server-side? Is there no performance impact to use database way?  And I knew the global scope variable in the cakePHP is 'configure' collection, then should I use it for storing thousands users' locations information?

Comment: I'm thinking we're going a bit off topic here, but the database is pretty good at answering queries so storing data on the local web machine(s) is probably not a good idea. If the database is too slow to answer every request (not sure about your scale), you could try using caching like memcache, but adding things to the local configuration of the web machine to speed them up will greatly complicate things like adding more web machines.

Comment: Maybe in our case, it is not suitable to use database for storing thousands of users _realtime locations_ which updating in a period time. What we think about now is that using a **global collection(variable)** to keep these information as it is not more than _key/value_ pair in which is _id and coordinates_ for each user. So, any further suggestion, please?

Comment: I can only advice against storing things in memory only, if you are still going that route I can't really help you. You'll need to find someone with more CakePHP specific knowledge.

Comment: Thank you, Joachim! You gave me great hint! I am trying using the database way and will back later...